# No error being displayed with GET request

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

I am trying to display the results of this get request but it is not returning any results or errors.

Even when testing I have tried to hardcode and append `<li>my job</li>` but that doesn't work either.

Have you got any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function (){

  var $jobs = $('#jobs');

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    username: '5afe0f90-3480-4d47-8206-3529815a610a',
    password: '',
    crossDomain: true,
    url: 'http://www.reed.co.uk/api/1.0/search?keywords=construction&location=sheffield',
    success: function(jobs) {
      $.each(jobs, function(i, job){
        $jobs.append('<li>my job</li>')
      });
    }
  });

});
</script>

<ul id="jobs"></ul>
```

Comment: did you check error callback?

Comment: @leafeve what would the error call back be? sorry I am new to this.

Comment: You only have a success callback; you need to add an error callback.

Comment: add error callback and check agian https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/jquery/jquery-ajax-method

Comment: Have you checked the response in the Network tab of your browser's dev tools? What does the response look like? Is it valid JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an error callback in the options object:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function (){

  var $jobs = $('#jobs');

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    username: '5afe0f90-3480-4d47-8206-3529815a610a',
    password: '',
    crossDomain: true,
    url: 'http://www.reed.co.uk/api/1.0/search?keywords=construction&location=sheffield',
    success: function(jobs) {
      $.each(jobs, function(i, job){
        $jobs.append('<li>my job</li>')
      });
    },
    error: (err)=> {alert(err)}
  });

});
</script>

<ul id="jobs"></ul>
```

There are four returned statuses, in addition to success:

- **timeout** - when your specified timeout is exceeded
- **error** - http error, like 404
- **notmodified** - when requested resource was not modified since last request
- **parsererror** - when an xml/json response is bad

So, you may want to check each of those out to determine the best way to handle each response. :)

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks to be good except the success callback. You have two options, take a look below to see what suites your needs better.

**Option 1:** Use an [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
$(function (){
    var $jobs = $('#jobs');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        username: '5afe0f90-3480-4d47-8206-3529815a610a',
        password: '',
        crossDomain: true,
        url: 'http://www.reed.co.uk/api/1.0/search?keywords=construction&location=sheffield',
        success: (jobs) => {
            $.each(jobs, function(i, job){
                $jobs.append('<li>my job</li>')
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**Option 2:** Move either the definition of `$jobs` into the same context in the callback or eliminate it.

```
$(function (){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        username: '5afe0f90-3480-4d47-8206-3529815a610a',
        password: '',
        crossDomain: true,
        url: 'http://www.reed.co.uk/api/1.0/search?keywords=construction&location=sheffield',
        success: function(jobs) {
            $.each(jobs, function(i, job){
                $('#jobs').append('<li>my job</li>')
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**Explanation:**
This is caused by the context being different for where the variables are defined. With the `function` definition it will use it own context, with the `arrow function` it will use the current context.

If you are still having an issue check the Console to see if any errors are being produced by a Server Response Code, `CORS`, `Mixed Content`, etc.

Comment: Hi Noah, 

I have tried both of your solutions but nothing is showing on the page.

I change the dataType to JSONP to get around the CORS issue.

Have you tried the script?